# How to make jar with Spring Bean inside, and use it in a SpringBoot Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, plugins

I have to make a plugin manager that handle Spring Bean inside jar contains in a specific external folder, in my case it's *externalPlugin*.

The folder *externalPlugin* is in my classpath.

My problem is that spring don't load beans when there are inside the jar. 
If the jar file is extracted in */externalPlugin* folder, Spring boot loads correctly the beans.

Is there a specific way to create jar , that spring loads correctly bean inside JAR? or even is it possible to load bean in external Jar?

Thank you for your time.

In my spring boot application, in order to load external Bean, I use the annotation

```
@ComponentScan({"com.app","com.plugin"})
```

To know if my bean are loaded I use and print the result of

```
String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractPlugin.class);
```

external plugin jars are created as follow with jar cvf command

```sh
/externalPlugin/pluginA.jar 
|-META-INF/
|  |-MANIFEST.mf
|
|-com/
  |-plugin/
      |- beanA1.class
      |- beanA2.class
```

```java
package com.plugin
@Component
public class BeanA1 extends AbstractPlugin{
}

package com.plugin
@Component
public class BeanA2 extends AbstractPlugin{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found what i needed 
http://www.codevomit.xyz/bootlog/blog/how-to-provide-spring-boot-fat-jar

and specialy generate jar with eclispe